# How to properly Send Email Using Cron job in my Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I have a markdown Birthday Notification email Template. I want to send a notification to user on their birthday using Cron job. The Cron job works perfectly but isn't working when I try to send email or add Email function to handle it.

This is my Code please

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Mail\BirthdaymessageMail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Models\Employee;

class BirthdayCron extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'birthday:cron';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Notify Employee On Birthday';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->birthDayNotification();
    }


    private function birthDayNotification()
    {
        Mail::to('asamoa69@yahoo.com')->send(new BirthdaymessageMail());
    }
}
```

Please what's the right way to do this? I need assistance. Thank you.

Comment: The code seems fine have you checked the logs for errors?

Comment: Please verify that you added your credentials for SMTP in the .env file first.